# Is it possible to measure the electric current speed through the wire by this method?

Tags: forces, electricity, rotation, speed

This method is very simple but I am not sure if it would provide accurate measurements.The current electrons deriving from the battery should have some speed and in that way should interact with the coil shown on the picture by pushing the atoms of the coil lattice until the lattice gains the speed equal to the speed of the electrons so it starts rotating.Of course the contacts of the coil with the wire should be of negligible friction and the coil should be as symmetric as possible to provide neat rotation.If the drift velocity of electrons is let say 0.2 mm/s should then the coil rotate at that velocity? [image]

Comment: Consider a reasonable current, e.g. 5 Amps. How many electrons per second does this correspond to? Given a reasonable cross sectional area of the wire, and the free electron density of copper (about $8 x 10^28$ per $m^3$, what is the drift velocity of the electrons? Given the mass of the electrons, what kind of momentum are we looking at?

Comment: Related given that the method cited by the OP will not work. [How to measure the speed of an electric current?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/637532/how-to-measure-the-speed-of-an-electric-current/637640#637640)

Comment: @MartinCR Are You saying that the battery has no enough energy to force the electrons against the atoms of the coil. If there is current this current should have a lot of energy given by the battery so a speed and if it interacts with the coil I think it should give rise to two effects :motion and vibration of the atoms....

Comment: @ KrešimirBradvica not at all: the battery has plenty of energy. However the drift velocity of the electrons is very low (typically fractions of a mm per sec)

Comment: @MartinCR Should then the coil rotate this drift velocity let say 0.2mm/s?

Comment: Wait, the coil rotates because there are counteracting magnetic forces, not because of colliding electrons!

Answer (score 1):

The electromagnetic wave propagates through the wire at the speed of light. Not exactly, but for purposes of this experiment you can think of this to be true. It is no less than half of the speed of light.

Our *macroscopic understanding* of current is via flow of electrons. But electrons do not actually travel down the wire. They do move, but at a *drift speed* on the order of 1 mm/s. When we press the light switch, it does not take minutes for light bulb to turn on or off. In other words, electron flow is not the main mechanism which is responsible for power (signal) transmission.

Having this in mind, what exactly do you want to measure?

Comment: The battery carries energy so the energy drains by electrons flow from - pole to +pole. But they pass through the coil which I described as of negligable disipation of energy so should those electrons transfer energy to the coil that is free to rotate by pushing its atoms and by warming it? Can we compare the DC current with a river transfering energy to a turbine?

Answer (score 1):

A [back of the envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-of-the-envelope_calculation) in terms of momentum conservation calculation might indicate the difficulty of observing an effect?

The current is switched on and free elections in the copper wire, starting from rest, drift at your estimate of $0.2\,\rm mm \, s^{-1}$.

To conserve momentum the copper lattice starts to drift in the opposite direction at a speed $v$.

Putting in some numbers, for the relative atomic mass of copper $(63.5)$ and that of an electron $(1/1840)$, and assuming momentum conservation gives, $\dfrac{1}{1840} \times 0.2 \times 10^{-3} = 63.5 \times v \Rightarrow \mathbf {v\approx 2\times 10^{-9} \,\rm m \, s^{-1}}$.

Comment: But, correct me if I am wrong, is this same as saying that e.g. the river water molecule mass is much less then the mass of an iron turbine so as water molecules have a small mass they could not move enough the heavy turbine? Of course there should be a long lasting acceleration.... but eventualy the turbine will gain the river speed...